# AWS CloudTrail Lookup Events API

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to use [LookupEvents API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/API_LookupEvents.html) using Postman as the user agent. 
When I set filter in Body as raw Json, I am still getting all logs instead of just one. Any Idea how to do this?
Method: Post
Content-type: application/json 
or 
Content-type: application/x-amz-json-1.0
I also tried raw body to as text/json.

```
{
    "LookupAttributes": [ 
      { 
         "AttributeKey": "EventName",
         "AttributeValue": "ConsoleLogin"
      }
    ],
    "MaxResults": 1
}
```

Comment: Are you making use of API Gateway to make the request in Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a poorly documented API!  I eventually got this working, but the steps weren't easy to find.

Make sure your request:

- Method is `POST`.
- Has no query string parameters
- Includes `Content-Type` of `application/x-amz-json-1.1`.
- Contains an `x-amz-target` header with value `com.amazonaws.cloudtrail.v20131101.CloudTrail_20131101.LookupEvents`.

The ["Common Parameters" documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html) is a little misleading, as it seems to imply that `Action` belongs in the query string.  It does not.

In practice, having `Action` in the query string seems to bring back events with any `EventName`, and does not restrict the number of results.  It's as if the entire request body is ignored.

---

cURL command, with AWS signature stuff removed:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://cloudtrail.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'x-amz-target: com.amazonaws.cloudtrail.v20131101.CloudTrail_20131101.LookupEvents' \
--data-raw '{
    "LookupAttributes": [ 
      { 
         "AttributeKey": "EventName",
         "AttributeValue": "ConsoleLogin"
      }
    ],
    "MaxResults": 2
}'
```

---

I couldn't find the `x-amz-target` documented anywhere.  To get the value, I set up `mitmproxy` and looked at the calls generated by CLI commands.

Comment: Brilliant !!! That worked for me. Thanks a lot.
But I agree, very poor documentation.